# How to connect SAP SQL Anywhere server using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, sqlanywhere

I have made multiple attempts, but regrettably, I am unable to establish a connection. If anyone possesses the knowledge on how to connect, I kindly request your assistance. I extend my gratitude in advance.

1. Firstly, I added jconn4 JAR file.
2. Secondly, I included the database connectivity in the application properties.
   `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlanywhere:ManageEngine:2638/ManageEngine spring.datasource.username=Admin spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD spring.datasource.driver-class-name=sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver`
3. Finally, I performed some actions to verify whether it is functioning correctly.

Comment: An external jar file, what did you inclue? What properties did you set? There is far too little information to begin answering this.

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlanywhere:ManageEngine:2638/ManageEngine
spring.datasource.username=Admin
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver

Comment: jconn4 jar file

Comment: Don't add additional information as comments, instead edit your question!. ALso what isn't working, as that isn't clear as well.